# How to add a new field to an existing json record inside an array

Tags: json, mongodb

I have collection like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5437c1e8c56c92098f684f"),
    "name" : "Mongo",
    "authors" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "author" : "jack"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "author" : "mack"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add a new field i.e. `edition_year` to every record available inside authors array so that my collection will look like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5437c1e8c56c92098f684f"),
    "name" : "Mongo",
    "authors" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "author" : "jack",
            "edition_year" : 2018
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "author" : "mack",
            "edition_year" : 2017 
        }
    ]
}
```

What `update` command do i have to write?

Comment: Do you want to set the same value for every edition_year or specify it explicitly for each author ?

Comment: @mickl no i just want to set a default value like `null` or `0` while updating the authors `array` by adding new field `edition_year`....

Comment: @mickl this docs is really helpful but in this docs it is only written that how to update the existing fields....but i want to add a new field with default value like `0`...it will be really helpful if you can share the code a bit...

Comment: please take a look at my answer

Comment: You have to upgrade your mongodb version to use the all positional `$[]` operator

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet may be you are right...i have to upgrade it.....Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the all positional operator [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-all-documents-in-an-array)

```
db.col.update({},{ $set: { "authors.$[].edition_year": 2017 } }, { multi: true })
```

Comment: Thanks for your support but it's showing error a little bit....
`errmsg : cannot use the part (authors of authors.$[].edition_year) to traverse the element`

Comment: Had the same error message on 3.6.0 but it works on higher versions (tested on 3.6.5) it can be a solution for you if you can update your MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it will set default value to 0 for all of your authors array object in each document.

```
db.your_collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
 var newAuthors=doc.authors;
 newAuthors.forEach(function(author){
   //sets default value=0;  
   author.edition_year=0
 });
 db.your_collection.update({_id:doc._id},{$set:{authors:newAuthors}})
})
```

Comment: You're pulling all the dcuments into the memory while he's asking about `update` solution

Comment: It is only for setting the default value of an existing field but i want to add new field `edition_year : 0` to every json record....

Comment: Nah, it is for adding new field edition_year to every authors array objects. In case it is already present then only it will reset it to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your support....i tried but not working....i mean `script` is running fine but it's showing `0` records updated...

Comment: @Biswajit I have updated the script, it was missing the param inside inner foreach before. Let me know if it works or not.